How do I add "fiscal" fields on an Opportunity to a custom report type?
My underlying question is, why can't I add the "Fiscal Period" field to a custom report type but I'm also curious more broadly about where or how those fields are defined.
When comparing an object in the console to the Object Manager in Setup, there are a number of discrepancies between fields. Some of them I can take a guess at (see screenshot below) but some of them are more mysterious.


Are my guesses above correct?
If so, are the "fiscal" fields also internally calculated (presumably based on CloseDate and the companies Fiscal Year Settings)?
If not, where do they come from?
How do I figure out why IqScore shows up in Object Manager but not in the console?

And finally, re-stating the main question, why can't I display the Fiscal Period field in a Custom Report Type (when it is available on a standard Opportunity report)?

